# Query with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm making a sequelize query like this:

```
const users = await User.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" as name`)],
    where: { status: `[${USER_STATUS.ACTIVE}]`, organizationId: orgId }
  });
```

I got a problem

> "organization_users"."status" = ' "[1]" '

I want it to make a query like this:

> "organization_users"."status" = '[1]'

without the double quotes. Thank you. I try many way but did not work. Any help is appreciated!

I come to an answer on stackoverflow:

```
where: { status: { [Op.contains]: Sequelize.literal(`[${USER_STATUS.ACTIVE}]`) }, organizationId: orgId }
```

but the query is

> "organization_users"."status" @> [1]

Maybe this is a bug of sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this and it works:

```
  const users = await User.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'firstName',
      'lastName',
      Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" as name`)
    ],
    where: { status: { [Op.contains]: [USER_STATUS.ACTIVE] }, organizationId: orgId },
    include: [{ model: Role, as: 'roles', where: { roleName: role } }]
  }).map(u => {
    return u.dataValues;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the value of `${USER_STATUS.ACTIVE}` in a variable beforehand and then pass that variable as the `status`.

```
const st = "[" + ${USER_STATUS.ACTIVE} + "]";
const users = await User.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', Sequelize.literal(`"firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" as name`)],
    where: { status: st, organizationId: orgId }
  });
```